# Spring MVC accessing static resources not working for one level of hierarchy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using the below line of code in spring-servlet.xml for accessing the static content in my spring mvc project:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/">
```

[image: directory structure]

It works fine for level of hierarchy expect for one level which is marked as yellow and throws 404 error:

**Links which works fine:**
`http://{host:port}/res/jquery.1.8.js

http://{host:port}/res/css/test/test.css

http://{host:port}/res/css/test/test1/test1.css

http://{host:port}/res/img/test/test.png`



**Links which shows 404 error:**
`http://{host:port}/res/css/main.css

http://{host:port}/res/img/icon.png`



**Problem:**
`http://{host:port}/res/{folder}/{file}.extension`

So. there is some problem with about type of hierarchy..


Many Thanks in advance :)

Comment: which spring mvc version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I did not face this issue at all but your main.css under test not css, but I can not find reason for png file, please check file and folder names and hiraricy again.